# Drawing arrows and symbols in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a small tools for VS Code and the tool will need to draw arrows between symbols in the code.

Something along these lines.

[image]

Please forgive my skills with Paint.

What it is the best way to achieve this effect in VS Code?

Comment: have a look at Brackett Pair Colorizer extension, it you need to do this like you draw you need to implement a Webview and draw SVG on top of the source code, you need to supply code highlighting yourself

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of this answer!

Comment: the method used by `Brackett Pair Colorizer` with straight lines is a good compromise

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. The editor output in vscode is a list of DOM nodes (divs for the lines, spans for the syntactic elements). You cannot draw lines between DOM nodes.

If you had full control over the editor you could add an overlay over the entire text to draw the lines, but then you have to take care not to disturb the normal behavior of the editor and, after all, you don't have that kind of control.

A webview is **not** a good approach, as it would not only require to duplicate the work the normal editor does, it's also isolated and has no direct access to the main application, which means actions, language server support etc. don't work

Answer (score 0):

yes sure use this  Rainbow Brackets
its draw an arrow between the start and the end .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEibN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).